# HttpContext.Current is null while using FileSystemWatcher in C#

Tags: c#, filesystemwatcher

I use Forms authentication in my ASP.NET web application and I use FileSystemWatcher in a specific form.

It has two events `watcher_Changed` and `watcher_Created`. The events are getting invoked correctly. Once the event gets fired, the `HttpContext.Current` becomes null.

I don't understand if the session is being cleared by the `FileSystemWatcher`. Can anyone help me on this? The code is as follows.

```
void watcher_Created(object sender, FileSystemEventArgs e)
{
    watcher_Event(sender, e);
}

private void watcher_Event(object sender, FileSystemEventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        if (getUserName() != null)
        {
            //Some Code
        }
    }
}

public string getUserName()
{
    FormsIdentity useridentity = (FormsIdentity)HttpContext.Current.User.Identity;   //Exception is thrown here. ("Object reference not set to instance of an object")
    FormsAuthenticationTicket userticket = useridentity.Ticket;
    string username = userticket.Name;
    return username;
}
```

Thanks.

Comment: Where are you invoking this code? You only have a HttpContext User in some contexts, but not everywhere.

Comment: Or you should not use FileSystemWatcher at all. Consider other approaches please. HttpContext is thread local, so you should not expect it is not null in every threads.

Comment: @LexLi Can you please suggest any alternative approaches. Thanks very much.

Comment: You might post more details about this form's functionality and why you decided to use FileSystemWatcher at the very beginning. Then everyone can help shape it. Please consider post that as a new design question, because for this question, you already get a correct answer from @Douglas.

Comment: @LexLi Thanks very much for your reply. The functionality of the form is as follows.

1. The user logs in to the application.
2. The application should keep scanning a folder for any new files (XML) added. The path to the folder is read from the database.
3. When a new file is created in the folder, the application reads the relevant data from the XML file and displays information regarding that file in the form.

After searching for relevant controls to achieve this functionality, I went for FileSystemWatcher. I am not quite sure how effective it is in web applications.

Answer (score 1):

The `FileSystemWatcher.Changed` event is, by its nature, asynchronous. This means that it may be raised *after* the HTTP request has been serviced, and the session closed. If you want to associate a `FileSystemWatcher`’s events with the user that caused its creation, you need to maintain this explicitly – for example, by means of a dictionary that maps each `FileSystemWatcher` to the username.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Can you please explain in more detail how to map the FileSystemwatcher to a username?